# how to add message inbox icon in toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, icons, toolbar, inbox

in android toolbar i have a item that show inbox message.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/message"
    android:icon="@drawable/message"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

[icon in toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqhck.png)

how can i add like this icon(programmity)?
can i make a xml file?
example of toolbar that show inbox message(toolbar  is RTL and Persian)
[Persian toolbar  that have a inbox icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxK9O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've already solved a similar problem. 
Here's **my** post from [Add a TextView to the elements of a Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498137/add-a-textview-to-the-elements-of-a-toolbar)

> First, please learn how to create your own customized toolbar.
>
> Search for topics like this:
>   http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-android-creating-a-customized-toolbar--cms-24223
>
> Then you can create your toolbar as below ;-)
>
> Here is an example of your wannabe toolbar
>
> ```
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/shopping_bag"
>             android:layout_width="44dp"
>             android:layout_height="44dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/bag"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"></ImageView>
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/arrow"
>             android:layout_width="48dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:src="@drawable/usability_bidirectionality_guidelines_when3"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/number"
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/one"
>             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shopping_bag"
>             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopping_bag"/>
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> and it looks like:
>
> [image]
>
> To have a better look, find Material Design inspired icons.

I also see that you would need some Persian icons. If you cannot find them I would help you to create an example.

If you have any question please free to ask

Hope it help